# Regex expression to prevent character in a floating number

Tags: regex

I need to validate an user input which has need to meeting the following criteria

1. Only positive number
2. Can be a floating point number
3. If floating point number then there must be 2 numbers after decimal.

I have created a regex like this - `[0-9]+(.[0-9][0-9])?`

The only issue here is it accepts both `3.45` and `3a45` or any string for that matter in place of the decimal.

Can someone please let me know how to modify the regex for my needs?

Comment: Escape the dot `\.` and perhaps use word boundaries `\b[0-9]+(.[0-9][0-9])?\b`

Comment: `.` holds a special meaning in the regex word. Escape it using a backward slash to tell the regex engine to treat it like a normal dot character `\.`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird adding the boundaries for some reason throws validation error for floating numbers too

Comment: What is the tool or language? This pattern with word boundaries will prevent the digits to be part of a larger word `\b[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?\b` https://regex101.com/r/SE6Le5/1 Else try double escaping the backslashes.